# Creating alias in zshrc from json file

Tags: zsh

Does anyone know how to create alias in `zshrc` by reading reading JSON file from local machine

E.g.: my JSON file names is `ip.json` is as

```
{"local":"127.0.0.1"}
```

and want to create alias in `zshrc` as

```
alias local = "ssh root@127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jq` tool (available via `apt-get`) for that.

If the file `ip.json` has a json object that each key is a different host. Following your example (for any reason, you can not use `local` alias on zsh without getting issue with completion)

```
{
  "Local": "127.0.0.1",
  "remote": "192.168.0.5"
}
```

You can append this to your `zshrc` file:

```
# Use jq to get all keys in the root object and create a loop
for host in $(jq --raw-output 'keys | .[]' ip.json); do 
  # Get the key value of these keys and create the alias
  alias $host=ssh\ root@$(jq --raw-output ".$host?" ip.json)
done
```

Use `man jq` for more information about this tool.

Comment: Sorry but I cant upvote your answer right now due to low reputations but will surely do sometime later.